# VBScript Fill Web Login Form

Tags: vbscript

I can't figure out how can I fill Login Form with User and Pass and click on "OK" button.
I've tried several variants and nothing has been typed.
I made also I print screen with html code for each form.

[image]

```
On error resume next
Dim WshShell, objIE, ElementCol
Dim LinkHref

LinkHref = "https://www...."

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = False    

objIE.Navigate LinkHref 
wshShell.AppActivate objIE

Do While objIE.Busy
    wscript.sleep 100
Loop

Set ElementCol = objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each Link In ElementCol
    If Link.innerHTML = "Continue to this website (not recommended)." Then
        Link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next


objIE.Visible = True

objIE.Document.All.Item("S01LOGIN").value = "myusername"
    'objIE.Document.getElementByName("S01LOGIN").Value = "myusername"
    'objIE.document.getElementById("S01LOGIN").value = "myusername"

objIE.Document.All.Item("S02PASS").value = "mypass"
    'objIE.Document.getElementByName("S02PASS").Value = "mypass"
    'objIE.document.getElementById("S02PASS").value = "mypass"
```

I use IE11 and I think this is the problem

Comment: `objIE.Document.All.Item("S01LOGIN").value = "myusername"` should work

Comment: Should, but it doesn't work. The form is still empty.

Comment: I tested it by creating a similar html file and it works for me...perhaps something to do with the way your form is setup on the website

Comment: Can't open as it is asking for login at the first page

Comment: Indeed, but  to me it does not appear anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160788/discussion-between-bob-and-pankaj-jaju).

Comment: Why not use a proper password manager instead? Tools like KeePass and LastPass can autofill passwords on websites or other applications.